# Generating CSV from dynamic table using FileHelperEngine

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, filehelpers

I am exporting a table to CSV using `FileHelperEngine`
The problem here is that
`FileHelper` needs `[DelimitedRecord(",")]` class list<> of the columns that are been exported.

In my table, I have a Pivot that will give me table columns.
So the columns in the CSV will change based on values found by the pivot.

In the file helper engine, we have to pass a `list<t>` of a, separated column names

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[IgnoreFirst()]
public class MyProduct
{
    //Name
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    //Description, this attribute will handle the double quotes issue
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string Description{ get; set; }

}
```

In my case these columns will change so I tried a List of the table row type

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Dataset.TableRow>();
```

then it gives me an error

> The record class Object must be marked with the [DelimitedRecord] or [FixedLengthRecord] Attribute

I also tried a system.io approach that I found after some google

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

var columnNames = RiskDetailDataWithoutShowDetails.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
    var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Filename.csv"); 
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

but this will give me problems with , separated values in the data.

Is there a way to pass dynamic table to FileHelperEngine?

I read there is a `List<dynamic> list`. But did not get any way to use the same in the helperEngine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [class builder](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/N_FileHelpers_Dynamic.htm).

```
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("MyProduct", delimiter: ",");

cb.AddField("Name", typeof(string));
cb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both;

cb.AddField("Description", typeof(string));
cb.LastField.FieldQuoted = true;
cb.LastField.QuoteChar = '"';
cb.LastField.QuoteMode = QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth;

// etc... e.g., add a date field
cb.AddField("SomeDate", typeof(DateTime));

engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());

DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT("test.txt");
```

Comment: Heads up for anyone else who may find this. ".NET Standard FileHelpers dll currently does **not** contain ClassBuilder and CsvClassBuilder" - https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/blob/master/Readme.md